# Clojure and leiningen: declare and require namespace

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying understand how declare and require namespaces through lein. I created a project "interview", and inside "src/interview" I have a folder called "prompts", it has a file called rawlist.clj:

```
+ /interview               project root
|--+ /src                  lein src
|  |--+ /interview
|     |--+ core.clj
|     |--+ /prompts        my new folder
|        |--+ rawlist.clj
```

rawlist.clj file:

```
(ns interview.prompts.rawlist)
;...
```

**questions**:

1. How require rawlist in repl?

   - I'm trying `(require 'interview.prompts.rawlist)`
2. How require use some function of rawlist?
3. How correct create a test folder for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [clojure docs for require](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require). Here's an example where the namespace is given the alias `r` so that you can shorten the names.

```
(require [interview.prompts.rawlist :as r])
(r/your-function)
```

You can also refer to the full name at any time too:

```
(interview.prompts.rawlist/another-fn)
```

There are many ways to use require, e.g. with refer if you don't want a prefix. Say you have 3 functions f1,f2,f3, then you can refer to them in these ways:

```
(require [interview.prompts.rawlist :refer [f1 f2] :as r)
(f1)
(f2)
(r/f3)
```

Notice in third case, because it wasn't in the refer list, you have to use the `r` prefix.

For test folders, read the [documentation for leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies) where it is explained, but basically boils down to:

```
+ /interview
|--+ src/
|--+ test/
```

and the sub-folder structure follows exactly the same pattern as the src dir.

You can add additional folders in `project.clj` using `:source-paths` and `:test-paths` keys in the main project macro. See [the sample project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) for more information.

I recommend you absorb everything in the sample project above, and also read the [leiningen tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md).

Finally, when referring to functions in the [`ns` declaration](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns) in other sources (e.g. in your tests) you use the same format, but using the `:require` form:

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require [interview.prompts.rawlist :as r]))

(r/foo-fn)
```